# Firestore pagination backwards goes to first record always

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a simple Firestore pagination.
When it goes forward works as expected, but when it should go backwards it always goes to the first record.

I have been stuck here for a while, even crammed both (forward and backward) in the same function to ease the debugging.

Edit:

Added simplified version (still the same undesired results):

```
async init() {
  const result = await (await firestore())
    .collection('documents')
    .limit(this.limit)
    .orderBy('createTimestamp')
    // .orderBy('userName')
    .get()
  console.log(result)
  this.lastVisible = result.docs[result.docs.length - 1]
  ;[this.firstVisible] = result.docs
  result.forEach(doc => {
    console.log('doc', doc.data())
    this.myDocuments.push(doc)
  })
},
async forward() {
  const result = await (await firestore())
    .collection('documents')
    .orderBy('createTimestamp')
    // .orderBy('userName')
    .startAfter(this.lastVisible)
    .limit(this.limit)
    .get()
  this.lastVisible = result.docs[result.docs.length - 1]
  ;[this.firstVisible] = result.docs
  if (result.empty === false)
    result.forEach(doc => {
      console.log('doc', doc.data())
      this.myDocuments.push(doc)
    })
},
async backward() {
  const result = await (await firestore())
    .collection('documents')
    .orderBy('createTimestamp')
    // .orderBy('userName')
    .endBefore(this.lastVisible)
    .limit(this.limit)
    .get()
  this.lastVisible = result.docs[result.docs.length - 1]
  ;[this.firstVisible] = result.docs
  if (result.empty === false)
    result.forEach(doc => {
      console.log('doc', doc.data())
      this.myDocuments.push(doc)
    })
},
```

Added the calling method:

```
getAllDocuments: async ({ rootState, commit }, payload) => {
const documentsDb = new DocumentsDB(`${rootState.authentication.user.id}`)
console.log('Get all documents(admin)')
console.log('payload :>> ', payload)
const { startAt, endBefore, constraints, limit } = payload
console.log('startAt :>> ', startAt)
console.log('endBefore :>> ', endBefore)
console.log('limit :>> ', limit)
const documents = await documentsDb.readWithPagination(constraints, startAt, endBefore, limit)
console.log('documents', documents)
// const documents = await documentsDb.readAllAsAdmin()
// console.log('documents: ', documents)
commit('setDocuments', documents)  },
```

I left the console.log() for debuging reasons.

```
payload :>>  {constraints: null, endBefore: "2UxB7Z1HWCmvkEcfLZ5H", startAt: null, limit: 5}constraints: nullendBefore: "2UxB7Z1HWCmvkEcfLZ5H"limit: 5startAt: null__proto__: Object
```

Thhe original code

```
async readWithPagination(constraints = null, startAt = null, endBefore = null, limit = null) {
const collectionRef = (await firestore()).collection(this.collectionPath)
let query = collectionRef
if (limit) query = query.limit(limit)
query.orderBy('createTimestamp')
if (constraints) {
  constraints.forEach(constraint => {
    query = query.where(...constraint)
  })
}
query = query.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())
if (startAt) {
  query = query.startAfter(startAt)
}
if (endBefore) {
  query = query.endBefore(endBefore)
  console.log('query :>> ', query)
}
const formatResult = result =>
  result.docs.map(ref =>
    this.convertObjectTimestampPropertiesToDate({
      id: ref.id,
      ...ref.data(),
    })
  )
return query.get().then(formatResult)  }
```

Edit as requested in comments:

```
    dispatchPaginatedForwardDocuments(startAt = null) {
  const payload = {}
  payload.orderBy = [['createTimestamp', 'asc']]
  payload.constraints = [['status', '==', 4]]
  payload.limit = this.limit
  payload.startAt = startAt?.id || null
  this.$store.dispatch('admin/getPaginatedForwardDocuments', payload, { root: true })
},
dispatchPaginatedPrevDocuments() {
  const payload = {}
  payload.orderBy = [['createTimestamp', 'asc']]
  payload.constraints = [['status', '==', 4]]
  payload.limit = this.limit
  payload.startAt = this.lastDocument.id
  payload.endBefore = this.firstDocument.id
  this.$store.dispatch('admin/getPaginatedBackwardsDocuments', payload, { root: true })
},
```

And this:

```
import UserDocumentsDB from '@/firebase/user-documents-db'
// import UsersDB from '@/firebase/users-db'
import DocumentsDB from '@/firebase/documents-db'
import { storage } from 'firebase'

export default {



// Fetch documents with pagination forwards and constraints

  // This works as expected
  getPaginatedForwardDocuments: async ({ rootState, commit }, payload) => {
    const documentsDb = new DocumentsDB(`${rootState.authentication.user.id}`)
    const documents = await documentsDb.readPaginatedForward(payload)
    console.log('documents: ', documents)
    commit('setDocuments', documents)
  },

  
   // Fetch documents with pagination backwards and constraints
   
  getPaginatedBackwardsDocuments: async ({ rootState, commit }, payload) => {
    console.log('getPaginatedBackwardsDocuments', payload)
    const documentsDb = new DocumentsDB(`${rootState.authentication.user.id}`)
    const documents = await documentsDb.readPaginatedBackwards(payload)
    console.log('documents: ', documents)
    commit('setDocuments', documents)
  },
```

Comment: You'll need to add the code that calls this `readWithPagination` method, as that is likely where the problem lies. Ideally creating a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The new edit still doesn't show how you are defining your values for `constraints`, `startAt`, `endBefore` and `limit`. How are you moving forward through the pages? (e.g. setting a new `startAt` value?) How are you moving back? (e.g. are you setting a new `endBefore` value?). Add in small `showNextPage()` and `showPreviousPage()` functions that show what steps you are taking.

Comment: Added requested calls

Comment: Pardon, but I've noticed that the three functions you have do not declare the values `firstVisible` or `lastVisible`. Are they declared as part of the larger scope (brackets encompassing the three functions `init` `forward` and `backwards`?

Comment: They are computed values from Vue. In the other snippets I use   this.lastVisible = result.docs[result.docs.length - 1] in order to avoid some kind of mistake or bug regarding the document Id. Those are separate attempts that I have made to get the pagination right.

Comment: I'm probably wrong and being a little silly, but I feel I should insist on either making lastVisible a global variable or at least moving the `this.lastVisible = result.docs[result.docs.length - 1]` line before the async call, as it's the only real "flaw" I can see in your code, currently.

Comment: Did you figure this out? This was happening to me, and my only thought is that endBefore still means that the query starts at the beginning of the database and will end at the endBefore...but doesnt get there because the limitTo is reached.